# How to find the source of a rendered font-family

Tags: css, fonts

On [this](http://www.njit.edu/giving/waystogive/index.php) site I'm looking for the source of the font families `museo-slab-1`, `museo-slab-2`. I opened up Chrome's Developer Tools and searched through Sources and Resources for "`@import`" and "`@font-face`", but found no results. I also looked through every CSS file and couldn't find it.

Can someone provide me with the steps for tracking down font files in a way that isn't brute force like I was doing?

Comment: Judging by the classes attached to the the html files, they're added by JS. There do seem to be a lot of encoded data,font files so my guess it's one of those.

Comment: Does nobody notice the **obvious** Typekit scripts? Thats loaded using JS. Also, _don't steal fonts_ .

Comment: Ahh..yes, I was looking for the JS..not the CSS (doh!)

Comment: @somethinghere I'm not familiar with how Typekit works. Is it possible for me to directly get the font file that the JS file loads?

Comment: @SteveBahlmer Typekit is a paid font service that does its best to not allow its fonts to be easily stolen or grabbed. So I;d say no. Have a look for alternatives from Google Fonts or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Chrome, you can use the **Network Tab**, and then highlight over *Fonts* as shown here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [safaviehhome.com](http://safaviehhome.com/promotional/network.jpg))</sub>

You can then see information like Headers, Path, Size, etc. In regard to **Source**, it looks like they're loading the fonts with Data URI's which you can see in the headers tab.